# Firestore Android save failing - Could not reach Firestore backend

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Anyone seeing an issue saving documents with Firestore on Android? It seems to be happening on `'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.x'`.

Trying to do a simple save like so:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

db.collection("users").document("user1").set(user)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "Save OK")
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Log.e(TAG, "Save Failed")
    }
```

But neither listener is called. The only error I can see in the log is:

> W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach
>   Firestore backend.

Retrieving documents seems to be fine and downgrading to `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0` seems to resolve the problem.

Failing build.gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def dbflow_version = "4.2.4"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ce.test"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/ce.test/models']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.56.0.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.56.0.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.9'
    implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

Comment: Please add the content of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Done - question updated

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? I seem to have the same at the moment

Comment: I was a bit pressed so in the end had to go with v16. Haven't had chance to retest yet.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the success listener nor the failure listener will be called if your device can not reach Firestore backend. The success/failure listeners will only be called once the data is committed to, or rejected by the Firebase servers.

It is not mandatory but I recommend you to use the lastest version also for Firestore. For that, please change the following line of code:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
```

What instead is mandatory, you should add at the end of your file, the following line of code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please also don't forget to have in your build.gradle (Project) file, the following lines of code:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Please also don't forget to add INTERNET permission in the manifiest file.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the delay. I have tried the above but I'm still seeing the same issue. I was using 17.04 originally but was trying different versions as a test.

Comment: Managed to get some more details from the error -
`W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 2 times. Most recent error: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`

Comment: Admittedly that suggests there is a connection issue but as I said v16.0.0 works fine.

Comment: Have you tried to add INTERNET permission in the manifiest file?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: In my case INTERNET permission was missing.